# Is there a specific term for boasting about habitual actions?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

There are certain activities that all humans perform habitually. For example: Brushing teeth, having breakfast, lunch and dinner, a goodnight's sleep, etc. What if a person keeps on constantly boasting about such an action? For instance, just imagine him/her saying
"I brush my teeth twice daily. The toothpaste was so good. This is how you hold the toothbrush correctly..."
all the time.

Can we call this "overacting" or "dramatic"? Or is there any other specific term?

Comment: You want a word for boasting about trivial minor achievements? Or does it have to be more specific?

Comment: Yes. But, can things like brushing teeth be considered as achievements? There is no need to say that a person brushed teeth twice a day. That's an obvious fact. So, I'm looking for a word to describe "over emphasis on obvious things"

Comment: Part *manslaining* and part TMI.

Comment: Are you looking for overemphasis (as you say in a comment) or boasting (as you say in the title)? They are very different things. (BTW, this confusion might not exist if you included a sample sentence, [as required by the SWR tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests).)